# Create the responsive next / previous button for my project

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

could you guys please help me creating a next and previous buttons ? I've been struggling because of my bad javascript . I saw some people use Jquery and almost all Javascript. I'm practicing Javascript so there are a lot of things I don't know. Thank you very much.

Wants: Next / Previous button to go to next page and go back page if users want to read again that page.

Link of my demo: https://jsfiddle. net/hioihia123/zgjswtay/3/

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
  background: url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/groovepaper.png");
  font-family: 'Gelasio', serif;
}


main {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width:100%;
  margin-left : auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

main div {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6rem 5rem;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Ibarra Real Nova', serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
}

.right-page {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
.right-page p {
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

.right-page p:first-letter {
    font-family: 'Ibarra Real Nova', serif;
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    float: left;
    margin-top: .5rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    line-height: .7;
}

.left-page {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4rem;
}

.left-page small {
  font-style: italic;
}

.left-page img {
  max-width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: row;
    with: 100%;
    max-width: 1800px;
  }
  main div {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .left-page {
    padding-top: 14rem;
  }
  .right-page {
    padding-top: 6rem;
    max-height: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Old book Stories</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gelasio:400,400i|Ibarra+Real+Nova&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<main>
  <div class="left-page">
    <img src="https://www.oldbookillustrations.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/there-lonely.jpg"/>
    <small>But go there, lonely,<br>
At eventide,<br>
And hearken, hearken<br>
To the lisping tide.<br>
</small>
  </div>
  <div class="right-page">
    <h2>[ 1 ]</h2>
    <h1>Depender</h1>
    <p>
      En cuanto a todas las cosas que existen en el mundo, unas dependen de nosotros,
otras no dependen de nosotros. De nosotros dependen; nuestras opiniones, nuestros
movimientos, nuestros deseos, nuestras inclinaciones, nuestras aversiones; en una
palabra, todas nuestras acciones.<br>
Así, ante toda fantasía perturbadora, está presto a decir: <i>“Tu no eres sino una
      imaginación, y en absoluto eres lo que parece”</i>, enseguida examínala con atención y
ponla a prueba, para ello sírvete de las reglas que tienes, principalmente con esta
primera que es, a saber : de si la cosa que te hace penar es del número de aquellas
que dependen de nosotros o de aquellas que no están en nuestro poder. Di sin
      titubear: <i>“Esa en nada me atañe”.</i>
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
<!-- partial -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you simply add the `Previous` and `Next` buttons at the footer or somewhere you'd prefer, and link to appropriate pages? Won't that be simple enough in your case?

```html
<button onclick="location.href='https://google.com';">Previous</button>
<button onclick="location.href='https://facebook.com';">Next</button>
```

### UPDATE

Since you have all pages in a `div` inside `main`, its pretty easy to traverse through the pages, get the div that is visible, and hide it, and show the next or previous page depending upon the button clicked :)

Here's a sample:

```js
function changePage(prevOrNext) {
  var pages = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].children;
  for (let pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < pages.length; pageIndex++) {
    if (pages[pageIndex].style.display == "block") {
      if (prevOrNext == 1 && pageIndex < pages.length - 1) {
        pages[pageIndex].style.display = "none"
        pages[pageIndex + 1].style.display = "block"
        document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
      } else if (prevOrNext == 0 && pageIndex > 0) {
        pages[pageIndex].style.display = "none"
        pages[pageIndex - 1].style.display = "block"
        document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
  background: url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/groovepaper.png");
  font-family: 'Gelasio', serif;
}

main {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

main div {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6rem 5rem;
  display: none
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Ibarra Real Nova', serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
}

.right-page {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.right-page p {
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

.right-page p:first-letter {
  font-family: 'Ibarra Real Nova', serif;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  float: left;
  margin-top: .5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  line-height: .7;
}

.left-page {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 4rem;
}

.left-page small {
  font-style: italic;
}

.left-page img {
  max-width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: row;
    with: 100%;
    max-width: 1800px;
  }
  main div {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .left-page {
    padding-top: 14rem;
  }
  .right-page {
    padding-top: 6rem;
    max-height: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Old book Stories</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gelasio:400,400i|Ibarra+Real+Nova&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <main>
    <div class="left-page" style="display: block">
      <img src="https://www.oldbookillustrations.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/there-lonely.jpg" />
      <small>But go there, lonely,<br>
At eventide,<br>
And hearken, hearken<br>
To the lisping tide.<br>
</small>
    </div>
    <div class="right-page">
      <h2>[ 1 ]</h2>
      <h1>Depender</h1>
      <p>
        En cuanto a todas las cosas que existen en el mundo, unas dependen de nosotros, otras no dependen de nosotros. De nosotros dependen; nuestras opiniones, nuestros movimientos, nuestros deseos, nuestras inclinaciones, nuestras aversiones; en una palabra,
        todas nuestras acciones.<br> Así, ante toda fantasía perturbadora, está presto a decir: <i>“Tu no eres sino una
      imaginación, y en absoluto eres lo que parece”</i>, enseguida examínala con atención y ponla a prueba, para ello sírvete de las reglas que tienes, principalmente con esta primera que es, a saber : de si la cosa que te hace penar es del número de
        aquellas que dependen de nosotros o de aquellas que no están en nuestro poder. Di sin titubear: <i>“Esa en nada me atañe”.</i>
      </p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <!-- partial -->

</body>

<footer style="text-align: center">
  <button id="prev" onclick="changePage(0)">Previous</button>
  <button id="next" onclick="changePage(1)">Next</button>
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh I want to add next/ prev button like an image slider but in my case a book pages. Just want it to prettier, but my skills are suck :((

Comment: Thanks for explaining your use case, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so so much, you just saved me. I can't say thank enough. May I ask what do you call the javascript you just used ? I am learning Javascript and want to know everything :D

Comment: The JavaScript I used doesn't include any library. Its called the `Vanilla/Pure JavaScript`